# Does the Fn Lock (FnLk) on Thinkpad T440s work well with Linux?

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

I'm considering to buy a Lenovo Thinkpad T440s and to install Linux on it.

According to the user guide and photos of T440s, to use F1-F12 you have to hold down the Fn key, or use Fn+Esc to enable "Fn Lock"(FnLk).

Can anybody who has a T440s tell me whether FnLk works with Linux? Or does it rely on some Windows only driver? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, I tried it,

Works just fine on Ubuntu 13.10. If FNLK is on, the FN key has a small light on constantly as indicator